# AS3: Mouse Speed affecting volume

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using this code to detect the speed of the mouse using the `ENTER_FRAME` function. Speed of the mouse affects my mp3 which is playing on a loop. By using `ENTER_FRAME` it's updating by the frame rate, and is making the music sound really stuttered and messy.

Is there a way to ease in the volume (still using `ENTER_FRAME`) or will my mp3 always be affected this way?

```
var mySound1:Sound = new Sound();
mySound1.load(new URLRequest("AStringsMinor.mp3"));

var myChannel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
myChannel1 = mySound1.play(0, 999);

var prevPt:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY); 

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mouseSpeed); 

function mouseSpeed(e:Event)
{     
    var xspeed:Number = Math.abs(mouseX - prevPt.x);     
    var yspeed:Number = Math.abs(mouseY - prevPt.y);    
    var speed:Number = (xspeed + yspeed) / 100;
    prevPt = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);    

    myChannel1.soundTransform = myTransform1;
    myTransform1.volume = speed;
}
```

Comment: What's the FPS of the program?

Comment: its just the standard 24 fps

Comment: That doesn't work, its still jumping up/down to the next volume reading and making it sound really stuttered (with clipping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should ease your speed change by averaging ~5 seconds' worth of mouse speeds.

```
var speeds:Vector.<Number>;
var spn:int; // how many are there
var spi:int; // current index
// into initialization code:
spn=Math.ceil(5.0*stage.frameRate); // 5.0 is a number of seconds to average
speeds=new Vector.<Number>(spn,true);
for (spi=spn-1;spi>=0;spi--) speeds[spi]=0; // explicit init
spi=0;
// the function gets updated
function mouseSpeed(e:Event)
{     
    var xspeed:Number = Math.abs(mouseX - prevPt.x);     
    var yspeed:Number = Math.abs(mouseY - prevPt.y);    
    var speed:Number = (xspeed + yspeed) / 100;
    prevPt = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);    
    speeds[spi++]=speed; // record current speed
    if (spi==spn) spi=0; // wrap
    speed=0;
    for (var n:int=spn-1;n>=0;n--) speed+=speeds[n]; // sum all recorded speeds
    myChannel1.soundTransform = myTransform1;
    myTransform1.volume = speed/spn; // and now average it
}
```